# Stream microphone through PC over

Tags: windows, audio, vlc-media-player, streaming, microphone

I have a microphone hooked up to a Windows 7 PC. I need to broadcast this microphone live across my local network to Android/iPhone devices connected by wi-fi. I can't seem to find a method to get this to work. I spent hours researching and trying to stream from VLC Media player, and the corresponding VLC app for Android. I could not get this to work. Does anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could multicast an udp stream to your local network from [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and play it from your mobile device, on Android I use MX Player. My setup:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="USB Mic (2- Samson GoMic)" -c:a libmp3lame -f mpegts udp://192.168.0.255:12345
```

To get your device name you can use

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

I can also get VLC to work with these settings:[image: first][image: second]

Comment: Those are the same VLC settings I used. I can see my mic level as I speak into it in the Windows Volume Mixer, but I see no indication in VLC that it is receiving any audio, even when the proper input is selected. Have you found a way to see the level there? Maybe my sound isn't even making it into VLC.

Comment: @SomeGuy In image 1, left of device name you can set mic volumes and before selecting http streaming method there's an option to play the stream locally. There's also the possibility that your mic is used by some other application that locks it. Try shutting down any such applications or editing your mic's advanced properties and disabling "exclusive mode" (and maybe rebooting).

Comment: Great! I got VLC working by using your screenshots. I guess I was expecting some indication in VLC that there was streaming going on, such as the mic volume level showing somewhere. The only way to tell that there is streaming going on is that the window title says "Streaming", and who ever looks at the window title? Thank you!

I am successfully streaming to a Windows PC using VLC, and an Android device using a fork called JoeVLC.

Comment: How can you setup Mx Player to play a lan stream ?

Answer (score 0):

VLC is a great cross platform application.  PulseAudio is a cross platform sound system.  PulseAudio for windows would require more advanced skills to multicast sound over the network and maybe even getting it to run.  PulseAudio is often the default on Linux systems nowadays and is ported to BSD, MAC and even Windows versions.

The PulseAudio project describes itself as a proxy server for sound and does things like 
["... transferring audio to a different machine."](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/)

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful.
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=91996

> Firstly you will want prove out your audio input by opening "Open Capture device"
> Video device should be set to "none"
> Audio device configured as necessary to your desired input.
> When this is proven and working, then move on to streaming
>
> This is a computer to computer LAN solution using http (I do not have an Ipod)
>
> Open streaming (Capture device) in the GUI with video set to "none" and audio set to desired input configuration
> Click "Stream" button
> In the next "Source" window click "Next" button
> In the next "Destinations" window, optionally check the Display Locally box
> Then, select "http" from the dropdown menu and click the Add button beside it.
> This setting can usually be left at default of port 8080 with no path appended.
> In the Transcoding Options box below, select "Audio mp3" and ensure the transcoding checkbox is ticked
> Click "Next"
> In the final "Options" window
> Click "Stream" button
>
> You should now be streaming your audio in mp3
>
> On the client (VLC) computer, you need to select "Open Network Stream" and enter the complete url of the streaming server IP
> Eg (with your ip) http://192.168.0.21:8080

Hope I am able to help.